# Function that is not differentiable at a point

Tags: functions

I am looking for a continuous function to be used in fourier series graph that have the same value at both $-\pi$ and $\pi$ but has a very poor differentiability at a point.

I have one: $\sqrt{(\pi\vert x\vert) - x^{2}}$ through trial and error and it indeed have poor differentiability at $x=0$. Now I have no issue computing its fourier coefficient for $a_{0}$ and $b_{n}$ but its another story for $a_{n}$. Hence I could not graph it. I have also consulted various books but to no avail.

Hence I would like to know if anyone here have a such function in mind so that I can graph its fourier's partial sums and compare it with its function.

Comment: If you just want to take a look, you can compute coefficient numerically. Or even ask, say, Mathematic to plot truncated Fourier series for this function - there is such routine.

Comment: @Ilya - Yes I did using Mathematica. When plotting the $a_{n}$, even Mathematica produced an error saying exceed limit, etc and couldn't continue. This equation took about 40 mins to be process by Mathematica on my computer.

Comment: This is the $a_{n}$ computed by Mathematica => $\frac{(\pi BesselJ[1, (\frac{n\pi}{2}] \cos \frac{n \pi}{2}}{n}$. When plotting it as a graph, Mathematica can't continue.

Comment: Why not use $f(x) = |x|$? You can find the corresponding Fourier series [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierSeries%5BAbs%5Bx%5D%2C+x%2C+3%5D).

Comment: @AymanHourieh - Yes I had done this. Thank you. I am looking for one other example.

Comment: Why not simply $x^2$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, extended periodically to the whole real line? It won't be differentiable at $x=\pi$.

Comment: I am looking for a function which like two lines meet at one point and its not differentiable there. For $x^{2}$, its just like one sided line only although it is symmetrical.

Comment: "Where two lines meet at one point"—Do you mean you want a function whose graph becomes vertical as you approach the singularity from either side?

Comment: How high a partial sum are you trying to plot? Sage has no trouble plotting partial sums up to frequency 243; it only takes a minute on my machine. Here's a plot of the partial sums up to frequencies 3, 9, and 81 (https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/afenyes/share/mounds/mounds.png), and the Sage code that made it (https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/afenyes/share/mounds/mounds.sage).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $2\pi$-periodic functions defined by
$$f(x):=\cos(\alpha x)\qquad(-\pi\leq x\leq \pi)$$
for noninteger $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$. They are even,  continuous, but not differentiable at odd multiples of $\pi$; and their Fourier coefficients are easy to compute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something simple and not differentiable at $x=0$, try the following:

$$ |x| = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n-1)^2} \cos{(2 n-1) x}$$

Plot the partial sums in Mathematica against $|x|$.  What happens at $x=0$?

Comment: Yes I had plotted $\vert x \vert$ as one of my example. I am looking for another one with the same value at $(-\pi,\pi)$ and had more worst differentiability at a point than $\vert x \vert$. The one I gave in my first post had a very bad differentiability at $x=0$ but too bad even Mathematica can't draw out its partial sums.

Comment: Another one to try might be $|x|^{-1/2}$.  Its Fourier transform has interesting properties at least.

Comment: From the graph of this function, I can't explain about the one point I need. I am trying to explain about the convergence and hence differentiability at one point just like $\vert x \vert$. I have even look through Handbooks of Mathematics & Tables and integrals reference books but to no avail.

Comment: Be careful re convergence of Fourier series at a point.  Fourier series are designed to converge to a function over an interval according to an $L^2$ metric (i.e., the integral of the square of the error vanishes as the number of terms in the partial sum increases).  At a particular point, however, you may never get convergence in the sense you hope.  An example is the Fourier series for $\sin{x}/x$, which is known for its Gibb's phenomenon.

Comment: That is true. I am trying to show Paul du Bois-Reymond work from 1876 that says continuous function whose Fourier series diverge at a point. At present even reviewing all the available journal, there is no such function stated anywhere except proofs given by various authors that based on partial sums if I remember correctly.